# Oracle golden gate replication master control table

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle-golden-gate

This is the same post on

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4194263

We have a design like this.

The lock service lock records being requested by the App Service.

And the lock service locks records in both nodes.

In order to release the lock in both nodes.

1. The ETL has to completed.
2. The Golden gate sync has to completed.

We can have a master control table in the ETL node to have a time-space
signature to tell if the ETL flow is completed.

However, how do we guarantee the master-control-signature is being the last piece data element being replicated across ??

As this is a ALL-OR-NOTHING atomic operation ??

When the lock is release, it will release both node.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think you are defeating the purpose of GoldenGate here.  By locking both sites/tables you are preventing transactions from flowing.  In normal ETL processing, you would make the changes in one set of tables and then replicate those changes to the target set.

In your diagram, you look like you are doing Active/Active (bi-directional) replication. ETL should only happen on one-side and then the target side should prevent any duplicates from coming back after it has been synced.

Don't see a reason for the locking service and you may be making headaches for yourself.